# Django Models: update field value on save

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that is accessed via an endpoint that uses the slug:

```
path('test/<str:slug>', TestView.as_view(), name='test_view'),
```

I want to create a dynamic link which requires knowledge of the slug so it can't be assigned on creation since the slug hasn't been generated yet. How can I update the dynamic_link field and update it on creation?

```
class TestModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    dynamic_link= models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), max_length=150, unique=True, populate_from=('name',))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   def update_dynamic_link(instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
           instance.dynamic_link = self.slug #Put whatever you want to assign
           instance.save(update_fields=['dynamic_link'])

   model.signals.post_save(update_dynamic_link, sender=TestModel)
```

Comment: I see the post_save signal is outside of this function. why is that? when would update_dynamic_link method be called?

Comment: So signals are like hooks that bind to your table, so whenever there is a save on "sender" on that table, pre and post signals are called. pre_save called before save happened and post_save is called after save is done. It's outside the function because it is linked to the table only once when your server starts.

Comment: okay.  what does the `update_fields` arguement do? Does this still trigger another post_save signal ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid triggering another save signal.

Comment: You can only avoid a second save if and only if you generate the slug by yourself and prepare dynamic_link before the first save. Otherwise, you have no other option because the slug will be auto generated on DB level and you can only access it after the first save process complete. Signal will be called twice but as the object is created only once, so the second call will not affect anything. For update_fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save